# the last element of a dataframe, pandas

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas

Here in the code I have accessed the max() in the array value . I want to access the last value of the dataframe. How can I do that ?

```
'horizontal': round(df[['x2', 'x3']].max().max(), 2),
'vertical': round(df[['y2', 'y3']].max().max() - self.height_outlet, 2),
'jet_elevation': math.floor((df[['y1']].max().max() - self.height_outlet) * 100) / 100,
```

I thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `arr[-1]` should work, iiuc

Comment: Hi,
That might be the answer. but in my example if I :
'horizontal': round(df[['x2', 'x3']].[-1], 2), I get an error. that's why I asked the question here.
I want the answer related to my example.

Comment: _"I tried the correct way but I get an error"_: The full traceback of the error is very relevant information. Please remember that you need to provide a [mre] that reproduces your problem, and a complete description of the problem. Stack Overflow users aren't able to find out details about your problem that you have not provided in your question. See  the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953)

Comment: Also it seems you're looking for the last element of a **dataframe**, not a plain array. If this is a pandas dataframe, please [edit] your question to reflect this, also tag it [tag:pandas]

Comment: @PranavHosangadi do you habe some solution for me ?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
print(array[-1])
```

This should print out the -1th, or last, term in the array.

Comment: That might be the answer. but in my example if I :
'horizontal': round(df[['x2', 'x3']].[-1], 2), I get an error. that's why I asked the question here.
I want the answer related to my example.

Comment: Please specify more information and possibly edit the original question as to produce an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Try changing the line to ```'horizontal': round(df[['x2', 'x3']][-1], 2)```

Comment: @Alexhammer Don't include the dot before [-1]. You're not calling a method, you're just indexing an array. I recommend you split your indexes and splices up into variables. It makes your code easier to read.